How to delete agent.* fields from filebeat?
I want to omit agent.id and agent.type fields which are added by filebeat (by default). I have tried drop_fields processor but it didn't work. I am using filebeat 7.16.3. Please tell how to drop these fields?
Following is the filebeat.yml file:
filebeat.inputs:
- input_type: log
  paths: [/var/log/log.json]
  scan_frequency: 3m
  processors:
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["agent.type", "agent.id"]
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
      process_array: false
      max_depth: 1
      target: ""
      overwrite_keys: false
      add_error_key: true

  fields:
    topic: logs
output.kafka:
   hosts: ["192.168.0.155:9092","192.168.0.155:9093","192.168.0.155:9094"]
   topic: "%{[fields.topic]}"


Not sure if you have solved this already, but I think the problem is an indentation error? You need 4 spaces before - drop_fields:. Here is a link to someone with a similar issue to you.
You can also try to use ingest pipeline processors to remove these agent fields in Kibana. You can read more about the Elasticsearch ingest pipeline here.

In my case, when I applied processors out pf the type section, it worked.
filebeat.inputs:
- input_type: log
  paths: [/var/log/log.json]
  scan_frequency: 3m
  processors:
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
      process_array: false
      max_depth: 1
      target: ""
      overwrite_keys: false
      add_error_key: true

  fields:
    topic: logs

processors:
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["agent.ephemeral_id","agent.hostname","agent.type","agent.version", "ecs", "log.offset", "host"]

output.kafka:
   hosts: ["192.168.0.155:9092","192.168.0.155:9093","192.168.0.155:9094"]
   topic: "%{[fields.topic]}"

